# Best practices for importing rarely used package in Python

Tags: python, python-import

My Python package depends on an external library for a few of it's functions. This is a non-Python package and can be difficult to install, so I'd like users to still be able to use my package but have it fail when using any functions that depend on this non-Python package.

**What is the standard practice for this?** I could only import the non-Python package inside the methods that use it, but I really hate doing this

My current setup:

```
myInterface.py
myPackage/
--classA.py
--classB.py
```

The interfaces script `myInterface.py` imports `classA` and `classB` and `classB` imports the non-Python package. If the import fails I print a warning. If `myMethod` is called and the package isn't installed there will be some error downstream but I do not catch it anywhere, nor do I warn the user.

`classB` is imported every time the interface script is called so I can't have anything fail there, which is why I included the `pass`. Like I said above, I could import inside the method and have it fail there, but I really like keeping all of my imports in one place.

From classB.py

```
try:
    import someWeirdPackage
except ImportError:
    print("Cannot import someWeirdPackage")
    pass

class ClassB():
    ...
    def myMethod():
        swp = someWeirdPackage()
        ...
```

Comment: is `classB` is **all** *classB.py* has, then I do not understand the purpose of the `pass`. Otherwise I would go against purity and opt for practicality (import it inside the `class` definition)

Comment: `ClassB` is the only class in classB.py but only 2-3 methods depend on `someWeirdPackage`, so I use the `pass` so one can use other methods from this class.

Comment: I don't know if it's a possibility in the code your writing, but many packages have ways to program the needed functionality in a more round about way, and are packaged for convenience. Perhaps if you're only using a couple things from `someWeirdPackage` there would be a way to program that functionality yourself as to not have to import the package?

Comment: @DavyM I definitely can't do that :) , I'm importing the Stanford statistical parser: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure that there's any best practice in this situation, but I would redefine the function if it's not supported:

```
def warn_import():
    print("Cannot import someWeirdPackage")

try:
    import someWeirdPackage
    external_func = someWeirdPackage
except ImportError:
    external_func = warn_import


class ClassB():
    def myMethod(self):
        swp = external_func()


b = ClassB()
b.myMethod()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are only importing one external library, I would go for something along these lines:

```
try:
    import weirdModule
    available = True
except ImportError:
    available = False

def func_requiring_weirdmodule():
    if not available:
        raise ImportError('weirdModule not available')
    ...
```

The conditional and error checking is only needed if you want to give more descriptive errors. If not you can omit it and let python throw the corresponding error when trying to calling a non-imported module, as you do in your current setup.

If multiple functions do use `weirdModule`, you can wrap the checking into a function:

```
def require_weird_module():
    if not available:
        raise ImportError('weirdModule not available')

def f1():
    require_weird_module()
    ...

def f2():
    require_weird_module()
    ...
```

---

On the other hand, if you have multiple libraries to be imported by different functions, you can load them dynamically. Although it doesn't look pretty, python caches them and there is nothing wrong with it. I would use `importlib`

```
import importlib

def func_requiring_weirdmodule():
    weirdModule = importlib.import_module('weirdModule')
```

Again, if multiple of your functions import complicated external modules you can wrap them into:

```
def import_external(name):
    return importlib.import_module(name)

def f1():
    weird1 = import_external('weirdModule1')


def f2():
    weird2 = import_external('weirdModule2')
```

And last, you could create a handler to prevent importing the same module twice, something along the lines of:

```
class Importer(object):

    __loaded__ = {}

    @staticmethod
    def import_external(name):
        if name in Importer.__loaded__:
            return Importer.__loaded__[name]
        mod = importlib.import_module(name)
        Importer.__loaded__[name] = mod
        return mod

def f1():
    weird = Importer.import_external('weird1')


def f2():
    weird = Importer.import_external('weird1')
```

Although I'm pretty sure that importlib does caching behing the scenes and you don't really need for manual caching.

---

In short, although it does look ugly, there is nothing wrong with importing modules dynamically in python. In fact, a lot of libraries rely on this. On the other hand, if it is just for an special case of 3 methods accessing 1 external function, do use your approach or my first one in case you cant to add custom sception handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate classes for the two cases. The first will be used when the the package exist . The second will used when the package does not exist.

```
class ClassB1():
    def myMethod(self):
        print("someWeirdPackage exist")
        # do something

class ClassB2(ClassB1):
    def myMethod(self):
        print("someWeirdPackage does not exist")
        # do something or raise Exception

try:    
    import someWeirdPackage
    class ClassB(ClassB1):
        pass
except ImportError:
    class ClassB(ClassB2):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use given below approach to overcome the  problem  that  you're  facing.

```
class UnAvailableName(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.target = name

    def __getattr_(self, attr):
        raise ImportError("{} is not available.".format(attr))


try:
    import someWeirdPackage
except ImportError:
    print("Cannot import someWeirdPackage")
    someWeirdPackage = someWeirdPackage("someWeirdPackage")

class ClassB():
    def myMethod():
        swp = someWeirdPackage.hello()

a = ClassB()
a.myMethod()
```